# BigQuery update multi tables

Tags: google-bigquery

i'm holding huge transactions data on daily multi tables according the business date.
trascation_20140101
trascation_20140102
trascation_20140103..

the process flow is like that:
1.i''m loading the batch of new files that that arrive to temp table
2.i group by the transcation_date field in order to notice on which date is belong - 
  for each date i query the temp table on this date and insert it to the proper trasaction_YYYYMMDD
  table.
3.i'm doing part 2 in parallel in order to save time, because the temp table might contain data that belong to 20 days..

my challenge is what to do if one these process failed and other not..
i can't run it all again , since it will cause for duplications for the table that been already successfully update.

i solve these issue by managing this update, but it's seems to be too complex.

Is this best practice to deal with multi tables?
i will be glad to get some best practice in order to understand how others deals when they need to load the data to multi tables according to business date and **Not** just insert date(this is easy..)

Answer (score 1):

You could add an extra step in the middle, where instead of moving directly from today's temp table into the permanent business-date tables, you extract into temporary daily tables and then copy the data over to the permanent tables.

1. Query from today's temp table, sharded by day into `tmp_transaction_YYMMDD`.  Use `WRITE_EMPTY` or `WRITE_TRUNCATE` write disposition so that this step is idempotent.
2. Verify that all expected `tmp_transaction_YYMMDD` tables exist.  If not, debug failures and go back to step 1.
3. Run parallel copy jobs from each `tmp_transaction_YYMMDD` table to append to the corresponding permanent `transaction_YYMMDD` table.
4. Verify copy jobs succeeded.  If not, retry the individual failures from step 3.
5. Delete the `tmp_transaction_YYMMDD` tables.

The advantage of this is that you can catch query errors before affecting any of the end destination tables, then copy over all the added data at once.  You may still have the same issue if the copy jobs fail, but they should be easier to debug and retry individually.

Comment: How fast is copy append?

Comment: thanks a lot!, i really liked you solution. is very simple and clean. the only issue is..what you do if some of your copy failed and for the next hours you can't do it due to downtime failures. how you will know to recover automatically the specific copy that failed?

Comment: You can check success or failure of a copy job using jobs.get.  If you figure out which jobs failed, you can inspect those jobs' copy configurations to figure out what their source and destination tables are and retry/recover from the failure. https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/jobs#configuration.copy

Answer (score 0):

Our incentive for incremental load is cost, and therefore we interested in "touching each record only once".
We use table decorators to identify increment. We manage the increments timestamps independently, and add them to the query on run-time. It requires some logic to maintain, but nothing too complicated.

Comment: But its not business date. Its only insert timestamp

Comment: Same as concatenating insert date to table name, you can concatenated business date to where close, or to table name (this is what we do). once you replace a placeholder param within the query, you can do it with few.

Comment: ofcourse, but the question was how you handle with rollback.
when some of the inserts been succeed and some failed and you need to do rollback after you already insert some of your data

Comment: Using table decorators you can query a table in a snapshot manner, as long as it's in the past week. You can use that to roll back to a point in time prior to failure.

Comment: thanks! so you use the decorator in order to to rollback.
Is it really reliable ? 
Is it change to all operations types on tables (Insert Append/Copy Append/Truncate Overwrite..) ?

Comment: using decorator for rollback is good only if one process is insert rows in the same time but i you 2 process and succeed and not not.
using decorator rollback will delete the process that succeed.

Comment: It won't work for truncated. I suggest to use full load for recovery instead of managing increments. It's easier to control.